# Add/remove spinner gif to infinite scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have the following code to add more data as a user scrolls down:

```
$.ajax(
        { type: "POST",
        url: "default.aspx/fGetData", 
        data: varData,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json",
        async: "true",
        cache: "false",
        success: function (msg) {
            var myRes = JSON.parse(msg.d);
            $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dvGridItems01").append(myRes.pHTML);
            document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldAJAXSortLetter").value = myRes.strHiddenFieldAJAXSortLetter;
            document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldAJAXIsProcessing').value='0';
         },
        Error: function (x, e) { alert("Network error"); } }); 

        } });
```

Basically, more data (.pHTML) gets added to the div named dvGridItems01 every time a user scrolls down until there are no more items to fetch.

How can I temporarily show a div "dvSpinnerContainer" containing animated-spinner.gif when the data is being fetched and then hide it again once all the data (actually images) is showing?

Answer (score 1):

Use [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/) to display the loader and once the data is fetched, hide the loader.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="loader"><img src="loader.png"></div>
```

**Script:**

In the script, simply just add and remove the active class.

```
$.ajax( { 
    type: "POST",
    url: "default.aspx/fGetData", 
    data: varData,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
    dataType: "json",
    async: "true",
    cache: "false",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $('#loader').addClass('active'); // =====> add active class on loader
    }
    success: function (msg) {
        $('#loader').removeClass('active'); // =====> remove active class from loader

        var myRes = JSON.parse(msg.d);
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dvGridItems01").append(myRes.pHTML);
        document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldAJAXSortLetter").value = myRes.strHiddenFieldAJAXSortLetter;
        document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenFieldAJAXIsProcessing').value='0';
     },
    Error: function (x, e) { alert("Network error"); } }); 

 } });
```

Comment: Thanks. Should <div id='loader...> be included at the end of the backend HTML content given each time by .pHTML? If so, there will repeat  instances of it. Should I give it a specific id='loader2' id='loader3' etc, or should I remove it rather than hide it?

Comment: Not really, just make it a static html div else you will have to fetch it from backend and extra call will be made. so best is to just make a static html and hide and display it as per need.

Comment: Oh yes I see. I can put it in a div directly after the dvGridItems01 div so it always gets pushed down the page. Thanks.

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: One other thing, the content actually contains around 15 jpg images each time, quite large. If I remove the active class from the spinner in success: function (msg), will there still be a long delay before images show? In other words should I use a different event to hide it once the images are all showing?

Comment: How are you fetching the images? Is your ajax returing the src of the images?

Comment: Yes. Ajax just returns HTML from the backend that includes HTML like <img src='http://www.example.com/images/img7266482.jpg' alt='Red Apple'>Taste this red Apple.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax `beforeSend` & `complete` events for showing spinner.

```
beforeSend: function() {
    // add/show loader code here
},


complete: function() {
    // remove/hide loader code here
},
```

Comment: One other thing, the content actually contains around 15 jpg images each time, quite large. If I remove the active class from the spinner in complete: function() will there still be a long delay before images show? In other words should I use a different event to hide it once the images are all showing?

Comment: instead of "suceess call" do it inside complete: function(){}.. if its not satisfied your expectation you need some lazy load mechanism to be implemented there.